# 0 bytes of swap space available, recommended 10gb

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware

I am running Ubuntu14 on VMWare 12, on boot up the VM gives the hint 10.6GB of swap space recommended but 0 bytes of system swap space is available.

Within my VM I have partitioned 10.6gb of swap space through gparted on the partition */dev/sda3* which is swap space.

Then in my */etc/fstab* I have declared this UUID as swap space. e.g

```
UUID none swap sw 0 0
```

and I have turned swapon for this partition.

However every time I reboot the same message appears.

I am building the AOSP on my VM and using CCACHE to allow the build to be quicker so that the build only builds any elements which are changed even after a clean.

After my ccache has filled up this build should only take 20-30 mins tops. however it is still taking 1.5-2hrs.

The swap space being the issue I believe.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can stop this swapspace issue?

Comment: How did you create the swap space, through an installer or separately? In other words, has `mkswap` been run on the partition in any way?

Comment: i originally had an extended partition on an ext4 partition that was the standard. i then on gparted created a new partition of partition kind swap with the required memory. then i removed the old swap space and replaced it with the new one in the next partition swapped it on on the gparted gui. i then added it to the fstab. I have done mkswapon for the partition too.

Comment: There is `mkswap` and `swapon`, one of which formats the swap space (like `mkfs`), the other activates it. Did `swapon` produce any errors? Does the system show swap space in use after the command?

Comment: is that your actual `/etc/fstab` entry?  if so, that's not going to work.  you need `UUID=<actual UUID of swap partition>`, not just `UUID`.   e.g. on one of my systems, I have `UUID=db8bda5f-4f18-4abb-a151-08494e398047 none swap sw,discard,pri=10 0 0`

Comment: No i have my actual UUID in there, but its on my linux vm on another machine than writing this. No i never used actual mkswap. No swapon just says busy when its already turned on.

Comment: try `swapoff` on that swap device, then `mkswap`, then `swapon`.

Comment: @cas The solution to a "busy" message (or if you think someone is confused and telling you the wrong message) is never "let's just reformat the partition" !!  Please don't rely on `mkswap` checking for partitions that are already in use, unless you mention this explicitly, how to tell the exact version of mkswap that would be safe, how you know there are no circumstances where it gets it wrong, etc !!

Comment: @sourcejedi for a data partition, that's true.  for a swap partition (especially one that hasn't already been `mkswap`-ed so isn't in active use), there is no risk of any damage or data loss if you `swapoff` the partition and then `mkswap` it.  there's no data on it to be lost.

Comment: @cas it has been formatted and activated, it reports as "busy" !! what are you not reading ??  The implication the OP made is that the formatting was performed by GParted.  There is absolutely risk of data loss if you typo the partition name - or if the real problem was that you were confused about which partition was the swap partition.  You are _persistently_ confused about this situation, it is clearly not safe for you to be making `mkswap` suggestions.

Comment: The OP said "No i never used actual mkswap.".   re: typos - if we go around assuming things like that then where do we stop?  should i caution against pouring petrol on the computer and lighting a match? because that might cause a few problems too.  you're imagining a problem that does not exist.  running mkswap on a partition that isn't an active swap partition is not a risk.  panicking over unlikely events helps no-one, in fact it causes harm.  so quit being a panic-merchant.

Answer (score 3):

Web search indicates this message does not come from Ubuntu, but from VMWare *on the host computer*.  So you need to add the swap partition (or a swap file) on the host, not inside the VM.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/449643/vmware-player-warns-me-of-no-swap-whenever-i-launch-a-vm

I have no idea whether this would affect CCache performance, because I'm not familiar with VMWare, its use of swap, and this message.  On a Linux host I would allow maybe 1GB of swap, but apart from that the trick is not to over-commit compared to how much physical RAM you have!  Particularly with the default caching mode of Linux VMs created with virt-manager: the host provides extra read/write-back cache anyway, regardless of how much RAM the VM is allocated, so you can err towards the small side there without missing out on much.  It's like having a hard drive with gigabytes of (shared) cache, instead of megabytes :-D.

Comment: So, if I get it right, the simple answer to the question "how I can stop this swap-space issue?" would be to add 10GB of swap space in the host, not in the VM. That makes sense.

Comment: @xhienne edited to match your preferred wording.  Don't forget the `.6` as well :-P.

Comment: Thanks. No offense intended of course, you already had my vote. :)

Comment: I'm having a similar problem on a solid state drive (SSD) that I am running VMWare on. Host is Linux. Previous installs on spinning media I'd assign 8gb as swap space when partitioning the drive. On the SSD I only assigned 2gb. My VMWare workstation (v12.5) now runs very slow and I get a warning message similar to that described by the original poster. Any options other than increasing space on the SSD and thereby wearing the drive down?